# Infinispan JPA Cache loader?

Tags: caching, infinispan

How do I implement Infinispan JPA cache loader?is there any pattern or way to implement it in infinispan API?

Comment: Does it make sense to do? I'd suggest using the JDBC cache loader, as the CacheLoader API is all about loading and storing blobs: you can't map it to some known schema. If you need more flexible storage, have a look at Hibernate OGM

Comment: If It can store as Entity tables not like blobs It Can get More advantage with write behind caching

Answer (score 2):

Most existing CacheLoader implementations in Infinispan are assuming the data just needs storage and consider it blindly as an array of bytes. The integration API in Infinispan doesn't expose much of a context other than "store(Key,Value)" or "load(Key)". I'm oversimplifying a bit, but that's the core.

There is one exception which is the [LuceneCacheLoader](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/master/lucene-directory/src/main/java/org/infinispan/lucene/cachestore/LuceneCacheLoader.java). This was designed to work exclusively in combination with the [Lucene Directory for Infinispan](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Infinispan+as+a+Directory+for+Lucene), as it takes advantage of the fact

- It knows which types to expect
- Takes advantage of the known needs of the Directory (such as access pattern)

Have a look at the sources to get inspired; note I only implemented loading (it's a CacheLoader).

If you control both the application using Infinispan and the CacheLoader, you could take advantage of these details as well.

Tricky aspects:

- While writing multiple keys even in the same transaction, you'll have access to one entry at a time in the scope of the CacheLoader logic -> hard to map relations: have to deal with one entity at a time and "restore connections"
- With *write behind* you might receive entries out of order -> not sure how to deal with referential integrity
- With *write behind* you're not going to have the same Transactional context -> might be acceptable?

Taking these into account, I'm sure you could write one. How easy? That depends on your app.

I'm not sure if a general purpose solution could work. If you find out it can, please contribute it as it would be a great addition to the project.